# I need a html helper for my view but not too sure what one to use

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, view, html-helper

I am making an MVC3 web application.I have a table which is filled with data from my database but was wondering how i could make it show only the first three lines of my synopsis instead of all 10 lines.I think this has something to do with HTML Helpers but was wondering if any of you could help me find the right code?????
Any help would be greatful!

```
    @model IEnumerable<TheatreGroup.Models.Show>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Shows";
}
<h2>
    Shows</h2>

<p>Below is a list of shows which will be avalible in the next couple of weeks</p>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
    }
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.nameSortParm,})
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("writer", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.writerSortParm,})
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("synopsis", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.synopsisSortParm,  })
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model){

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.writer)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.synopsis)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.showid }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.showid }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.showid })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll divide my answer into two state:

1. You need the other 7 lines somewhere further down the flow of the page (like a 'show more results' link)
2. You don't need the rest of the list.

Solution 1:

Use what @Dangerous said.

```
@for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].name) // And the rest of the data
}
```

**please take note** that if you don't have 3 elements this code will throw an exception.
what you can do is check if the count is smaller than 3 and then run to that number.

You might also like to run still on the foreach loop and just give the  some sort of class that will hide it new { @class = 'hidden' } and then when you press some line, just use Javascript (jQuery) to show them.

Solution 2:

If you don't need the rest of the elements, when sending the model to the view just use take.

```
public ActionResult Action()
{
    var model = GetListFromDatabase().Take(3); // LINQ
    return View(model);
}
```

**You might need a ToList() to make it work, it depends**

that way you can keep your code as is, just shorten the number of elements sent to the View.

Hope it helps !

Comment: +1 to Omer for noticing that the view model should only really contain the information that is to be displayed in the view.  Solution 2 of these is better, populating only what is required in the controller.  Then you can use your original for each loop which is cleaner.  My solution was just a quick fix!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@foreach (var item in Model)` to display each line.

Try using `@for (int i=0; i<3; i++)` so that the loop just displays the first 3 items.

You will then need to reference the model as `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].name)` etc for the Display For's.  I believe that should work.